# Can't Set 'Value' of a custom ValueType

Tags: .net, vb.net, value-type

I have created a custom ValueType:

```
Private Structure MyValueType
    Private _integerValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(initValue As Integer)
        _integerValue = initValue
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _integerValue.ToString
    End Function
End Structure
```

But I can't work out how I can test the value such as this:

```
    Dim v As New MyValueType(3)
    Dim x As New MyValueType(4)

    If v = x Then 'fails compile
        MessageBox.Show("The values are the same")
    End If
```

Error:

```
Operator '='  is not defined for Types MyValueType and MyValueType
```

So how do I define Operators for my ValueType (I know this must be simple but I can't find an exmaple anywhere!)?

Note I don't want to test `If v.Equals(x)`

Comment: [Operator Overloading in Visual Basic 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following (you'll need to overload both the `=` and `<>` operators):

```
Sub Main
    Dim v As New MyValueType(3)
    Dim x As New MyValueType(4)

    If v <> x Then 'fails compile
        Console.WriteLine("The values are not the same")
    End If    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Structure MyValueType
    Private _integerValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(initValue As Integer)
        _integerValue = initValue
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _integerValue.ToString
    End Function

    Public Shared Operator =(
        ByVal left as MyValueType, 
        ByVal right as MyValueType) As Boolean

        If left.ToString() = right.ToString()
            Return True
        End If

        Return False   
    End Operator 

    Public Shared Operator <>(
        ByVal left as MyValueType, 
        ByVal right as MyValueType) As Boolean          

        Return Not (left = right)   
    End Operator     
End Structure
```

> **Note:** You'll probably want to implement `IEquatable(Of MyValueType)` as you'll gain some benefits from doing this and would be considered a "best practice."

Comment: Thanks Matt, Oded got me on these lines to start with. Note: `null` is not valid syntax in VB.NET

Comment: @MattWilko, It isn't always easy to switch mental contexts from C# to VB. Sorry about that. Anyway, I've updated the example to be a working one, and removed the null (nothing) checks as they aren't applicable to struts.

Comment: Thanks - very useful (incidentally I was implementing IEquatable I just posted a cut down example of code)